# Expand "See More" to obtain hidden list in Python

Tags: python-3.x, pycharm, selenium-chromedriver, expand

I am retrieving data from a site and I am only able to obtain the six list items in the free courses section that are presented prior to clicking on the "See More" link.

I have tried Seleniumm webdriver but I get permission errors that I am trying to overcome.  Is there any other way to retrieve the list items in the expanded view.

```
url = 'https://www.udacity.com/school-of-programming'
data = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(data.text, 'html.parser')

classes = soup.find('ul', {'class':'course-list'})
class_names = classes.find_all('a', {'class':'course-list__item__link ng- 
star-inserted'})

class_list = []
for a in class_names[0:]:
    result = a.text.strip()
    class_list.append(result)
```

I would like to retrieve the full list of free courses.  When trying to use Selenium, I get this error: selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: 'chromedriver_win32' executable may have wrong permissions. Please see https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/home

Answer (score 0):

The data is there you just need another selector. With bs4 4.7.1 you can use `:contains` and `:has` to appropriately target

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import requests

r = requests.get('https://www.udacity.com/school-of-programming')
soup = bs(r.content, 'lxml')
courses = [i.text for i in soup.select('.secondary-menu-item:not(:has(.nav-back))')]
print(courses)
```

Comment: That does bring list items from the whole page, but still doesn't include the free courses.  I am working on manipulating it so that I am able to retrieve the Free Courses list.

Comment: Hi, can you give an example of a free course that should be returned?

Comment: Here is code from the last list item visible and the next list item that is blank when the "See More" link is not clicked.  <li _ngcontent-iridium-us-c23="" class="course-list__item ng-star-inserted"><!----><a _ngcontent-iridium-us-c23="" class="course-list__item__link ng-star-inserted" target="_blank" href="/course/interactive-3d-graphics--cs291"> Interactive 3D Graphics</a></li><li _ngcontent-iridium-us-c23="" class="course-list__item ng-star-inserted"><!----></li>